# Why the display style is not working

Tags: math-mode, inline, displaystyle

I have the following formula that is in display mode

```
\begin{equation*}
 x_k = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N_1} \sum_{j=1}^{N_2} T_{i,j,k} u_i v_j, \quad k=1,\dots,N_3.
 \end{equation*}
```

But it is displayed in inline mode, why do the limits and the font style not get the display style by default?

[image]

My config object:

[image]

Comment: First of drop `\limits`, not needed in displayed math. If you're still having problems and this compiles without error (just getting a pdf is not the same as compiling without error) then plade post a full but minimal example that at your end give the image posted

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the screenshot you posted using just the LaTeX shown above.

Comment: I can reproduce the output (with many LaTeX errors) if the code is used in the cell of an `array` environment. Please, show a minimal example with some more details.

Comment: Welcome. // Please improve your question: screenshots of code are close to a no-go, simply for practical reasons. If you ask for help, make it easy for people to do so. // Also, how is your HTML configuration related to LaTeX? Why do you think a conversions will give you the same quality as a LaTeX compile? Things like that should go into your question, via the EDIT button. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I am unable to reproduce the screenshot you posted if I make your code snippet *minimally compilable*:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'equation*' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  x_k = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N_1} \sum_{j=1}^{N_2} T_{i,j,k} u_i v_j, 
       \quad k=1,\dots,N_3.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Please review your LaTeX code carefully.

Incidentally, since the contents of an `equation*` environment are rendered in `\displaystyle` by default, there's no point in providing the `\limits` placement modifier. To cut down on code clutter, I'd strongly recommend you omit the `\limits` directive.

Comment: I added the same equation but still I have the same issue,
Note: If I replace \begin{equation*} with \begin{align*} then it works fine

Comment: @RawanAlsmadi - I had to make several assumptions, such as choosing a particular document class, in order to make your code snippet minimally compilable. Based on these assumptions -- which I don't think were all that unreasonable -- I reported that I was unable to reproduce the screenshot you posted.  Your latest comment very much confirms that your document setup must differ in one or more important aspects from the assumptions I came up with. I'm in no position to speculate what the key differences may be.